# Post list category plugin alphabetical order

Tags: categories, order

Is there a way we can set these to list the posts in the category by alphabetical  order?

Comment: Please explain your problem better.

Comment: It is not just unclear what you are asking, but it seem that you are asking for support for third party plugins, which is off topic here. If you have an issue with downloaded or purchased themes and plugins, contact the relative authors. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Paste this in your `function.php`

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse_175699_alphabetical_order');

function wpse_175699_alphabetical_order($query) {

  if (is_category()) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'title');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
  }

}
```

Comment: Although your answer is missing vital explanation to what your code does and how it works, you still get my upvote as this is the correct method to get the desired result :-)

Comment: Thank you Pieter :) I believe that the code should speak for itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about general Wordpress coding, have a look here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Alphabetizing_Posts

Look for 'order' => 'ASC' which will order posts in Ascending value (eg. A-Z)

If you're talking about using or adapting a plugin, have a look in the plugin's instructions. For instance, the plugin [List Category Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/) has instructions about ordering posts in [its notes here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/).

In that plugin's case, you'd want to use the shortcode: [catlist order=asc]

Comment: The page you are referring to in the codex is actually a shame, incomplete and incorrect. It is **not** the correct method to order post alphabetically on a category page. The method described in the other answer is correct. That should be in the codex, not the current crap